# Как сделать чтобы при масштабировании страница оставалась по центру?

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap4

Задний фон на 1920рх. При увеличении основной контейнер смещается в сторону. При 100% масштабе получается что страница выравнивается от заднего фона. При меньшем масштабе получается по центру.

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="header_main">
                    <div class="header_main_content_title">
                        Практический марафон, основанный на синтезе нумерологии, практической психологии и
                        работы с
                        бессознательным от эксперта в области трансперсональной психологии и известного
                        нумеролога —
                        Мары Борониной
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


.header
    width: 1920px
    margin: 0 auto
    background-color: #555
    &_main
        height: 860px
        padding-top: 27px
        &_title
            margin: 0 auto
```

масштаб 100%
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

масштаб 67%
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сам немного разобрался, но не пойму как сделать? Когда убираю ширину 1920, нужный блок встаёт по центру. Но мне нужен задний фон на 1920

Comment: без кода или ссылки на сайт никто вам не скажет

Comment: вместо ```width``` используйте ```max-width```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это помогло. Как именно это работает? Есть же еще min-width. И как в данном случае ставить + что ответ был полезен и поблагодарить?

Answer (score 0):

Секция `header` должна быть на всю ширину экрана. Все, что центрируется должно находится в `container`.

Вы задаете для `header` ширину и центрируете:

```
width: 1920px
margin: 0 auto
```

Это нужно задавать в `container`. Для экранов меньше 1920px нужно задавать другую ширину контейнера - через медиа запросы.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).